# How can I deal with very large image processing in CUDA? Images > 2GB

Tags: image, cuda, gpu

I'm currently using `cudaMallocPitch()` to load images right now but it fails for very large images since there is not enough memory available. I have very, very large images to deal with since I'm working with hyperspectral images. How can I partially load an image, process it and then put the results on disk?

Comment: What sort of processing algorithm are you running on the large images?

Comment: You need to specify what the operations are you're trying to perform. Most likely you can split processing up in (possibly overlapping) blocks which you can then run sequentially or even over multiple GPUs. But you need to tell us what you're doing.

Comment: I'm developing detection algorithms for hyperspectral images.

Answer (score 10):

There are CUDA boards with enough memory to accommodate a 2G image - the Tesla M2050 and M2070 have 3GB and 6GB of memory, respectively.  If you can't justify fronting the money for such hardware, for $2.10/hr, you can "rent" a server with two Tesla M2050's on Amazon EC2 using the cg1.4xlarge instance type.

For images larger than the amount of video memory available, you will have to manually cycle image data to and from video memory with explicit memcpy's, processing it in chunks.  If the processing time is comparable to the amount of time needed to transfer the data to/from the board, you also should consider using asynchronous memcpy and CUDA streams, to overlap the transfers and computation.

Comment: Also used pinned memory to exploit DMA transfers (e.g., use cudaMallocHost for host memory allocations with page-locked memory).

Comment: Yes-asynchronous memcpy only works on page-locked memory.